# Adding elements to a layout inside an Async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My application is reading database rows and adding `TableRows` with a `TextView` (or multiple) to a `TableLayout`. Since the database can be quite big, I need to implement a progress bar and subsequently an `Async` task to do the reading from the database and adding to the layout. What I have now doesn't work, because I stuffed all the processes inside the `doInBackground`. Are there any elements that I need to move outside the Async task and make it work? If not, how can I arrange them so I don't get errors on execution?

```
public class orders extends Activity {
private DataBaseManager dataBase;

//put the table name and column in constants
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "clients";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String COLUMN_CLIENTS = "code";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LoadData task = new LoadData();
    task.execute();
}
public class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
//declare other objects as per your need
@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this, "Progress Dialog Title Text","Process Description Text", true);
};      
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
{   
    setContentView(R.layout.clients);
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.clieTable);
    newClientButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.newClientButton);
    dataBase = DataBaseManager.instance();

    Cursor cursor = dataBase.select("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID));


            TextView textClieCode = new TextView(this);
            textClieCode.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, 60, 0.04f));
            textClieCode.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.row_background));
            textClieCode.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            textClieCode.setTextSize(18);

            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            tr.addView(textClieCode);
            tl.addView(tr);

            String code = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CLIENTS));

            textClieCode.append(" " + code + "\n");                   
        }

    }
    return null;
}       
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
{
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
};
```

}
}

Comment: Whats the output of your code? Does it crash?

Comment: @NadeemIqbal Yes, Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that this code will help you. But You should use **[runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))**

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
{   
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setContentView(R.layout.clients);


            TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.clieTable);
            newClientButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.newClientButton);
            dataBase = DataBaseManager.instance();

            Cursor cursor = dataBase.select("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID));
                TextView textClieCode = new TextView(this);
                textClieCode.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, 60, 0.04f));
                textClieCode.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.row_background));
                textClieCode.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                textClieCode.setTextSize(18);

                    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                    tr.addView(textClieCode);
                    tl.addView(tr);

                    String code = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CLIENTS));

                    textClieCode.append(" " + code + "\n");                   
                }
            }

        }
    });
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, although I get several other errors, this is definitely on track.

Comment: DO NOT DO THAT. The entire doInBackground method is executed in the main thread, so what is the point of having the asynchronous task ?

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTasks also have a `onProgressUpdate` (which is run on the UI thread) with can be called form the `DoInBackground` method to update the UI.

You should call `publishProgress` with the data you want to display to trigger the update(type depends on the second type of your task `AsyncTask<Void, **String**, Void>` and modify your UI in that method.

Example :

```
 private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
         publishProgress(i);
     }
     return -1;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }
 }
```

And, don't call `setContentView(R.layout.clients);` in the background thread...